# set list data in model through APIView

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have a django model where i store the data through post request, in API View how i have a Array field in django model

```
Class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_1 = ArrayField(models.CharField())
    field_2 = ArrayField(models.CharField())



class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field_1', 'field_2')


class MyApiView(CreateAPIView):
    def my_method():
        validated_data = MySerializer.data
        field_1 = validated_data.get('field_1', [])
        field_2 = validated_data.get('field_2', [])
        obj = serializer.save()
        obj.field_1.append(field_1)
        obj.field_1.append(field_2)
        obj.save()
```

when i append the data to field_1  in model it is storing as list of list field_1 = [['a', 'b', 'c']] but the desired output should be field_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'] how can i acheive this

Comment: Please include the actual classes of View, and Serializer.

Comment: maybe instead of using`.append(...)` use [`.extend(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting list of lists because you are appending the `field_1` and `field_2` lists in the `obj.field_1`. What you actually need to do is to extend the `obj.field_1` list like this:

```
obj.field_1.extend(field_1)
obj.field_1.extend(field_2)
obj.save()
```

Or:

```
obj.field_1 += field_1
obj.field_1 += field_2
obj.save()
```